# Многопоточная запись в Oracle (DOA+Delphi)

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, oracle

Задача состоит в записи с помощью большого кол-ва потоков данных в Oracle. Для
этого в каждом потоке объявлено

```
type 
    TinfoTask = class (Tobject)  
    pQuery: Pointer;
    nThread: integer;
end;

var
 TaskRunQuery: ITask;  //Task для выполнения запроса

const
    quTimeOut: integer = 30000; //через сколько срубать выполнение запроса
```

В конструкторе потока:

```
  oraSession := TOracleSession.Create(nil);
  oraSession.LogonUsername := AUser;
  oraSession.LogonPassword := APasswd;
  oraSession.LogonDatabase := AConnectionString;
  oraSession.ThreadSafe := True;
  oraSession.LogOn;

  OracleQuery:= TOracleQuery.create(nil);
  OracleQuery.Session:=oraSession;
  OracleQuery.DeleteVariables;
  OracleQuery.sql.Text:='хранимая процедура'
  OracleQuery.DeclareVariable('param1', otInteger);
  OracleQuery.DeclareVariable('param2', otDate);
  OracleQuery.DimPLSQLTable('param2', size_, 0);
  OracleQuery.DeclareVariable('param3', otDate);
  OracleQuery.DimPLSQLTable('param3', size_, 0);
  OracleQuery.DeclareVariable('param4', otString);
  OracleQuery.DimPLSQLTable('param4', size_, 10);

    infoTask:= TinfoTask.Create;
    infoTask.pQuery:= @ods;
    infoTask.nThread:= Fnum
```

Объявлена процедура

```
procedure RunQuery(Sender: TObject);
var
  num: integer;
begin
  TaskError:= false;
  if Sender <> nil then
  begin
    num:= TinfoTask(Sender).nThread;
    try
      TOracleQuery(TinfoTask(Sender).pQuery^).Execute;
    except
    on E: exception do
      begin
        WriteLog('(!ОШИБКА)' + #13#10 + e.Message);
        TaskError:= true;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

В самом потоке происходит выполнение запроса через TTask, чтобы можно было отменить выполнение записи, если тайм-аут превышен

```
OracleQuery.close;
  OracleQuery.SetVariable('param1', cnt);
  OracleQuery.SetVariable('param2', varP2);
  OracleQuery.SetVariable('param3', varP3);
  OracleQuery.SetVariable('param4', varP4);


  TaskRunQuery := TTask.Create(Tobject(infoTask), RunQuery);
  TaskRunQuery.Start;
    if TaskRunQuery.Wait(quTimeOut) then
    begin
      TaskInTime:= True;
    end
    else
    begin
      TaskInTime:= False;
      WriteLog(' Превышено время ожидания запроса (30 сек.)');
      oraSession.BreakExecution;
    end;
```

Все работает нормально, при небольшой нагрузке. Как выходим на 100 000 записей в секунду, все начинает тормозиться, память растет и т.д. и т.п. Может я не учел чего? (К самому серваку доступа нет)

Comment: Тормозится на клиенте или на сервере? Если на сервере, поставьте [ASH viewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ashv/) (если оракловый OEM недоступен), а там по обстоятельствам.

Comment: Время запроса возрастает в десятки раз. До сервера добраться не могу, но админ божиться, что у меня косяк, а сервер не нагруженный стоит. Видимо, на клиенте тормоза